# Firestore security rules with functions return unknown error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection of users:

```
users:
   userUid:
       group: "group_1"
       name: "Paul"
   userUid:
       group: "group_1"
       name: "Gregor"
   userUid:
       group: "group_2"
       name: "Mary"
```

and a collection of ShoppingLists:

```
shoppingList:
   listUid:
        isActive: true,
        group: "group_1",
        name: "list_ONE"
   listUid:
        isActive: false,
        group: "group_1",
        name: "list_TWO"
   listUid:
        isActive: true,
        group: "group_2",
        name: "list_THREE"
```

I would like to restrict the read/update access so that only people belonging to a specific group, can edit/read documents within the same group.

I tried with the following rule looking at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions), but in the Firabase console simulator I get an "unknown error" and I do not get any console hint about this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {      

    function signedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function getGroup(usr) {
      return usr.data.group;
    }

    function isInGroup(usr, groupName) {
       return signedIn() && (getGroup(usr) == groupName);
    }


    match /users/{user} {
      // Read access needed to get the user group
        allow read: if signedIn();  
    }


    match /shoppingLists/{shoppingList} {
      // Everybody can create a new list
      allow create: if signedIn();

      // Only people from the list group can read/update that list
      allow read: if isInGroup(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)), resource.data.group);

      allow update: if isInGroup(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)), request.resource.data.group)
                       && request.resource.data.isActive;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI if you want to format code in a question, you can select all the code and use the {} button in the editor to format the entire thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using get() correctly in your rules.  You're passing a string path to a document that involves collections and documents, but get() requires that you pass a path object that 1) is not a string, and 2) is prefixed with with `/databases/$(database)/documents`.  You should [read the documentation on accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) to see some examples, such as this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      // Make sure a 'users' document exists for the requesting user before
      // allowing any writes to the 'cities' collection
      allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))

      // Allow the user to delete cities if their user document has the
      // 'admin' field set to 'true'
      allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
    }
  }
}
```